# GUI tool for presenting connectivity status on a firewalled network with port blocks etc

Tags: firewall, internet-connection, monitoring, gui, blocking

The Israeli railway company has recently started a project of wireless LAN availability on its lines. Now, it's all in the flakey stages, sometimes things are up and sometimes they aren't; sometimes ports are blocked and sometimes they aren't. And what's more annoying is that I *think* that they have some sort of application-layer-level traffic analysis preventing HTTP proxying.

I would like to have some sort of a GUI tool which would try to connect to various hosts on various ports (perhaps using various protocols), with and without tunnelling on its own or through existing tunnels, giving me a more-or-less comprehensive picture of what's happening connection-wise.

Note that something like ShieldsUP is *not* relevant since I'm not interested in whether or not the outside world can connect to me (it can't).

Comment: Interesting question. On a related note, does TeamViewer work? It penetrated every company network I've been in so far... I don't know how, but it probably tunnels through a teamviewer official server... Through a http proxy... And it's still fast and speedy. If this question is purely for research and not practical use (which TeamViewer would cover), just ignore this :D